# Redirect everything except ?p=*

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

how can I configure a .htaccess file to redirect every link except

```
domain.com?p=*
```

and

```
domain.com/index.php?p=*
```

to domain.com

I hope you understand my question, thank you for every answer.
Greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if query string is p=(something)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=
# and request is for "/" or "/index.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
# pass it through, don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# otherwise, redirect everything else to http://domain.com/
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```